# Create new table or view or create stored proc, or create function? to have a new table with different fields

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Please help, I am working on a new project for Manhours Timekeeping. We have a production table called EmployeePunches where there are fields like EmployeeNumber,BusinessDate, Clockin, Clockout. Now the 3rd party application is looking for our old setup of manhours table where there are EmployeeNumber,BusinessDate,Time,Time_Event. The EmployeePunches table is fixed and they dont want to edit it. while the 3rd party application that access old manhours table is too expensive and will consume time to customize.

My recommendation is to create a new table, this newtable will get the data from EmployeePunches while the fields will change to manhours table where there is time_event - I=in and O=out to satisfy the requirements of the 3rd party application.

My question is what would be the best implementation for this type of scenario. Badly needed experts help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please explain your question in deep that what actually you want to achieve..

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking here. I get that you have a table whose schema you do not want to change, and an application you do no want to change, and now you need some intermediary "translator". But you need to be more specific about your needs. Are you only going to rename some columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best implementation is to use a view.  This makes sure that the underlying data is always aligned with the newest data in the table.

Backwards compatibility is a very good way to use views.

If you have a performance issue with the view, then investigate indexed views.  These allow you to build indexes on views to improve performance.

Comment: Thank you so much Gordon, but there are no entries from EmployeePunches table like I and O for the in and out. How will I update and create a field time_event in view? Thanks

Comment: This is my select query: from EmployeePunches
EmployeeNumber BusinessDate ClockIn ClockOut
6016257 10/1/2012 10/1/2012 7:20 10/1/2012 10:49
6016252 10/1/2012 10/1/2012 7:21 10/1/2012 16:43

while in old manhours table: this is the format. 
 employee_number | business_date |   time   | time_event
-----------------+---------------+----------+------------
 6015634         | 2018-01-05    | 23:00:00 | O
 3309446         | 2022-04-24    | 14:20:00 | I

Comment: and the output, we need is to get data from EmployeePunches but the format should be in old manhours table with time_event entries I and O, is this possible with view? thank you.

Comment: @tintin . . . Your view will join in the manhours table to get the information that you need.  You should post another question with the layout of the tables if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

You don't tell what the data dictionary of EmployeePunches neither provide sample data, but it looks like a view is the best approach here. A simple SELECT with the fields and change time_event.

Comment: Thank you so much koriander, im not that good in creating views, or creating complex queries, i appreciate your immediate response. If I do select with the field and change the time_event how will I insert or update the entries with I and O? there's no entries from EmployeePunches it just like ClockIn and Clockout as time in and out.